# Bind an element's text to a property of an object set as val of element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Well..what I said in my question title.

I have an element which value is set to an object because of a generic way in which we set an element's val from a plugin we made at work..

I would like to know if I can bind, using angularjs, the element's text to a property of that object setted as its current val..

Answer (score 0):

Sure, given a sample object:

```
$scope.myObj = {
    name: "Justin"
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myObj.name" />
```

That `input` is now bound to `myObj.name` - editing it will change the object.